# Bound for analytical function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be an analytical function that is not a Möbius transformation, with $f(0) = 0$. I now have to prove that there exists a positive number $\lambda_r < 1$ for every $r \in [0,1)$ such that

$|f(z)| \leq \lambda_r |z| \qquad $ if $|z| \leq r$.

I tried using Schwarz' lemma but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $r=0$ any $\lambda_r$ will do. For $0 < r < 1$ we have
$$
 \lambda_r = \max\left\{ \left|\frac{f(z) }{z}\right| : |z| \le  r\right\}  = \left|\frac{f(z_0) }{z_0}\right| \le 1
$$ 
because the function $f(z)/z$ has a removable singularity at zero, and the Schwarz Lemma tells us that the expression on the right is $\le 1$,
with equality only for functions of the form $f(z) = \alpha z$. Since Möbius transformation were excluded, $\lambda_r$ is strictly less than one.